# Unix: formatting data with the CLI

Tags: unix, pipe, command-line-interface

What I would like is a way to pipe the output of a program into another program that will format each line into a MySQL insert. Does Unix provide an easy way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this does what I need it to do

```
echo "something from file" | awk '{print "something left " $0 " something right" }'
```

Answer (score 1):

you should be looking at printf command in bash

http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/printf

Comment: I've seen this page but i can't figure out how to make printf take the input and put it in the middle of another string

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
echo "something" | while read line; do
  echo "INSERT INTO table VALUES($line);"
done > file
```

Answer (score 1):

To address your comment on Gurubaran's answer and give `printf` some TLC:

```
$ printf "something left %s something right\n" $(cat test.txt)
something left Test something right
$
```

Answer (score 1):

As you might have gathered from the other answers, there are a myriad ways to do it.  They've not even touched on `sed`, Perl, Python, and the like.  The key issue is 'how many values are there in each line of data', and what is the correct way of presenting that information to MySQL.  If the input lines are nicely formatted so that the data is ready for presentation, then it can be as simple as:

```
data-generator-script |
while read line
do
    echo "INSERT INTO Table VALUES($line);"
done
```

or:

```
data-generator-script |
sed 's/.*/INSERT INTO Table(Col1, Col2, …, ColN) VALUES(&);/'
```

On the other hand, if the data is presented with multiple values separated by blanks, with strings needing to be enclosed in quotes, then life is messier:

```
data-generator-script |
awk '{printf("INSERT INTO Table(Col1, Col2, …, ColN) VALUES(%d, '%s', …, %d);\n", $1, $2, …, $N);}'
```

If you have to split on some character other than blank, to allow multi-word strings, you again have to deal with more complex issues.  If it is something like a pipe `|` and it doesn't appear in the data, then you just need to add `-F'|'` to the `awk` script.  If the data is in CSV format, you may be able to use the first technique, but if there are multi-line strings in the data, you need a full CSV parser tool.